# Accessing the dom on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

This `ReactDOM.render()` method will add the HTML or the component to the DOM and it is similar when we append the node to the DOM. With that in mind is it a good practice to access the dom in react JS like the code example below :

```
function Component(){
  return(
     <h1 id="delete">"Hello World"</h1>
  );
}
div.render(<Component/>);

const h1 = document.getElementById("delete");
div.removeChild(h1)
```

In the above example, `div.render` will add a Component to the DOM because the Component is added to the DOM so I can access the `h1` by the id then I delete the `h1`.

But is this a good practice? Otherwise what problems can be caused by this?

Comment: Why would you do that in very first place?

Comment: A mix of paradigms. React typically uses refs to access the underlying dom.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of reasons why you may actually want to escape React component tree hierarchy (like when you need to position a modal dialog or something alike which introduces Stacking Context or content clipping concerns), but it's done in slightly different way.

You need to use React Portal, which is exposed via `createPortal` function of `react-dom` library, which accepts two arguments: a component you want to move and an actual DOM element where you want to render it. Assuming you have `<SomeComponent />` component defined somewhere else code will look something like:

```
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";
import { SomeComponent } from "./components/SomeComponent";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="main">
      {/* the rest of the code of the App */}
      createPortal(<SomeComponent />, document.getElementById("id"))
    </div>
  );
};
```

That'll render your component in the specified DOM node. There are some caveats though. You should understand that from React perspective this component will **still** be part of the render tree of the component that created `<SomeComponent />` element. In this case, the `<App />` component. That means that:

- if the re-render of `<App />` is triggered, `<SomeComponent />` will re-render as well
- if `<App />` unmounts, `<SomeComponent />` will disappear as well
- events that happen in `<SomeComponent />` will propagate in the `<App />` (they're part of React synthetic events)

Some things that will break:

- if you rely on CSS inheritance and cascading to style `<SomeComponent />` in the `main`, it won't work anymore:

```css
// won't worked with portalled component
.main .some-component-classname {
  color: green;
}
```

- if you try to add eventListener using ref for example, it won't work
- if you try to get `parentElement` it will return the `id` div, not the main app (though it's some kind of expected)

So while it's perfectly reasonable to use Portals and render to DOM node directly when you're dealing with something like modals or other things with combination of `position: relative` and `z-index` other than 0, notice how it's still following React declarative paradigm.

What you do in your example with direct component mounting/unmounting not only will break normal React rendering process, it will strip you off that nice declarative way of writing code and send you back to imperative hell, which causes me to question why do you need React in the first place.

Comment: sir so that mean i can't doing dom manipulation in dom ways like on javascript

Comment: Well, you certainly can. Nothing stops you from doing that (except terrible performance and some hard to investigate bugs). Question you need to ask yourself is why do you need React in the first place? The whole point of React is to abstract away direct DOM manipulation. Actually it's THE point of any component based framework out there. It's like you need a bike, then go buy car and chop it in half to make it two wheel. No point in doing that. Likewise, if you need direct DOM manipulation you'd be better off with something like jQuery or just vanilla JS.